# Children on a generation ship come to believe it's all a simulation

Tags: story-identification, generation-ship

I've had a story dancing just out of reach of memory for some time now. I keep thinking Vernor Vinge "A Fire Upon the Deep", but the Tine's world had breathable atmosphere so I don't think it's it.

The part I'm remembering is a generation ship type setting, one of the youth becomes delusional and doesn't believe they're in an actual spaceship, some fraction of the other children start to believe him, I think resulting in an attempt to "leave the simulation", resulting in disaster.

Edit: to elaborate further, the children are classmates. The one who has the delusions gets a following of students, causing the student body basically to take sides forming two factions. There are adults onboard but they either aren't aware or dismiss the children's beliefs as harmless. This was a full length novel, this plot line taking place in the middle third of the novel (approximately), and I read it 3 to 5 years ago, but the novel may be older than this.

Comment: Welcome! Can you add any more? Was it a novel or a short story? Where and when did you read it?

Comment: Memory's hazy on this one lol, I believe it was a full length novel and I read it somewhere in the last 3-5 years, it could have been considerably older though.

Comment: All info helps :) Please update the question with this and *anything* else you remember.

Comment: Will do, thanks!

Comment: There was a simillar 3 part TV series about a year ago where a generational ship actually was a simulation but no one on the ship knew it was a simulation. Unfortunately it seemed to end mid-story but it was good. I can't remember the name though.

Comment: A Fire Upon the Deep might also be triggering your memory if you read the sequel, Children of the Sky, in which growing up, a disturbing number of the children (who were in stasis pods for much of AFUTD)  start to believe that they'd been lied to and Blight was actually a GOOD thing that got stopped too early.  Which isn't the same thing, obviously, but has some similarities your memory might have latched onto.

Comment: I've read Children of the Sky and I think that's where the confusion was coming from but it was definitely Ark, it all came back as soon as I saw the book cover lol

Comment: @RReveley You could always ask it as a separate question, but you might be talking about _Ascension_? Six episodes though.

Comment: @RReveley I was going to mention that myself. It's three two-part episodes, which is unnecessarily confusing. Shows up on Netflix as six episodes, but labeled Chapter 1, Part 1, Chapter 1 Part 2, Chapter 2 Part 1, and so on.

Comment: That was it Ascension.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### This sounds like [*Ark* by Stephen Baxter](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2111628.Ark) (the sequel to *Flood*), published in 2009.

[image: Stephen Baxter – Ark]

a generation ship type setting:

> The events of *Ark* overlap with those of *Flood*: in preparation for a flood that will completely submerge the Earth's continents by 2052, the billionaire Nathan Lammockson builds *Ark Three*, a gigantic ship that will sail the waters of the drowned Earth. Skeptical of the project's viability, the U.S. government recruits billionaires Edward Kenzie, Patrick Groundwater and Jerzy Glemp to fund the construction of *Ark One* (later renamed *Project Nimrod*), a generation ship capable of superluminal travel using an Alcubierre warp drive. The plan is to fly *Ark One* to an Earth-like exoplanet and rebuild civilisation on the new world.

one of the youth becomes delusional and doesn't believe they're in an actual spaceship:

> During transit, it emerges that Zane has dissociative identity disorder due to abusive parenting and sexual molestation by his Academy tutor
>
> Kelly had kidnapped the ship's only doctor, so Zane is no longer undergoing therapy and spreads rumours that the ship is actually a virtual reality simulation.

some fraction of the other children start to believe him, I think resulting in an attempt to "leave the simulation", resulting in disaster:

> The shipborn children, having never seen Earth for themselves, believe him and start a mutiny. Hoping to reveal the ship to be a simulation, they remove a metal plate from the hull, causing an uncontrolled decompression which kills and injures many passengers.

(Quotes from [Wikipedia synopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ark_(novel)#Plot_summary))

Comment: That is EXACTLY it, thanks so much! Adding that to reading list to reread.